# why Navigation drawer ,no lintening MenuItem click?

Tags: java, android

I have my Activity and implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
,this is mi code is  onCreate , don't print clicked too . previously it worked normal, without any inconvenience

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
        binding.appBarMain.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
        NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.bringToFront();
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
```

when i use onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) , don't work but change fragments automatically

```
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        String title;
        boolean fragmentTransaction = false;
        Fragment fragment = null;
        System.out.println("clicked");
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                title = "MyText";
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
               args.putString("url", "MyText");
               fragment.setArguments(args);
               fragmentTransaction = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_gallery:
                title = "MyText2";
                Bundle args1 = new Bundle();
                args1.putString("url", "My Text2");
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(args1);
                fragmentTransaction = true;
                break;
          }
       
        if (fragmentTransaction) {
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, fragment)
                    .commit();
          
        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You are using a `NavHostFragment` and `NavController`. That means you should not be using any fragment transactions at all. That means that your `onNavigationItemSelected` is not going to work in any case. What are you actually trying to do that isn't done for you by [tying your menu items to navigation graph destinations](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#Tie-navdrawer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to implement your own NavigationItemSelectedListener, you shouldn't use the default setup in this line
`NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);` and you should comment/remove it.
as if you inspected this method you will find it uses its own NavigationItemSelectedListener.